# Integrating Equations with Units - 2023

Tags: kinematics, units

I have a worked example from a recorded lecture and lecture notes which I am having difficulty with regarding Rectilinear Motion in Mechanical Dynamics.

When I asked my lecturer about the following, I was advised that since velocity is a function of time and not a single constant scalar, one cannot treat the units as constant variables.

This appears foreign to me as in non-calculus derived equations I was taught to always use the units of measure as a type of calculation check for the values.

Instead, for physics phenomena inherently related by calculus equations, are there additional steps to reduce an equation so that all the units are the same in the equations final form?

Is there a general rule I don’t know about when it comes to the use of calculus in physics phenomena requiring the omission of incorporating the units or is it just specifically for units that have an inherent relationship when differentiating or integrating?

---

**Example Question**

For Rectilinear motion of a erratic (non-constant) acceleration past 8 seconds, determine the formula for velocity with respect to time *[v(t)]* with acceleration $a_\mathtt{ERRATIC}$
*(t) = (-1/8) *t* + 4. *

Using the formula for velocity with erratic acceleration as a function of time

$$
v= \int a_\mathtt{ERRATIC} \;dt
$$

Incorporating  $a_\mathtt{ERRATIC}$(t)

$$
=> v \; = \; \int \; (\frac {-1}8 t +4)  \;dt
$$

$$
\equiv \; v \; = \; \int \; \frac {-1}8 \; t \;dt \; + \int 4  \;dt
$$

Simplifying the equation as much as possible, I then have

$$
 v \; = \; \frac {-1}8 \int \; t \;dt \; + 4  \int 1 \;dt
$$

Incorporating the units,

$$
 v(m/s) \; = \; \frac {-1}8 \int \; t(s) \;dt \; + 4  \int 1 \;dt
$$

Treating the units as a constant as per [Integrating equations with units from old Stack Exchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/integrating-equations-with-units),

$$
 v(m/s) \; = \; \frac {-1}8 (s) \int \; t \;dt \; + 4  \int 1 \;dt
$$

Integrating, I get

$$
v(m/s) \; = \; \frac{-1}{8} (s) t^2 + 4t + C_1
$$

---

**Calculation Question 1.**

Relating to the previous calculation is that I presume that $t^2$ (as it pertains to units of time / seconds) seconds would be squared ($t^2 s^2$) and not cubed ($t^2 s s^2 $).

Continuing on with the calculation to isolate for $C_1$ and applying the respective units relating to the independent variable of time

$$
 C_1 \; = \;  v(m/s) \; \; + \frac{-1}{8} t^2 (s^2) - 4t(s)
$$

---

**Calculation Question 2.**

How then does velocity units *(m/s)* relate to time *(s)* ?

Is there another calculation step I can use so that I can incorporate the all units to result in a single equation with uniform units

Comment: In your example, the number $4$ is not just a number, but it must have units associated with it $4\;[m/s^2]$

Comment: Hello @GainKnowledgeDaily! Please, try to use informative titles for your questions (and maybe be as synthetic as possible: your preamble adds nothing to the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach is to do the calculation purely numerically, omitting all units, while keeping in mind the set of units you are working in. For example, if you are working in SI units, all velocities will always be in $\text{m/s}$, all accelerations in $\text{m/s}^2$, and so on.

If you do choose to keep track of all the units at every step, here is a consistent way to do this. You start with
$$a = \left(-\frac{1}{8\text{ s}}t+4\right) \text{ m/s}^2$$
or written in a slightly different, perhaps uglier way, if you prefer:
$$a = \left(-\frac{1}{8}\frac{t}{1\text{ s}}+4\right) \text{ m/s}^2.$$
After integrating you end up with
$$v = \left(-\frac{1}{16\text{ s}}t^2+4t\right) \text{ m/s}^2 + C_1=\left(-\frac{1}{16\text{ s}^2}t^2+\frac{4}{1 \text{ s}}t\right) \text{ m/s} + C_1$$
which can also be written in the alternative way
$$v = \left[-\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac t {1\text{ s}}\right)^2+4\frac t {1\text{ s}}\right] \text{ m/s} + C_1.$$

$C_1$ here has dimensions of velocity. Note that the quantities in these equations are not pure numbers anymore: they come with units. The nice thing about this is you don't need to specify what unit things are in: these equations still work if you plug in $t = 5 \text{ ns}$.

Comment: Thanks Puk, your answer has clarified how to solve such physics equations incorporating units with the two differernt approaches. Much appreciated.